# MySQL queries performance

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, performance-testing

I have database `catalogs` with 14000 records, 100 columns and just 2 columns with type longtext. This query was really slow - more than 40 seconds

```
SELECT
    id,
    title,
    pdf
FROM
    catalogs
WHERE
    (shop_id = 2597)
```

for experiement I create new database called `new_catalogs` with the same structure and data but I remove 2 columns with longtext type

Running the same query was double faster - 20 seconds.

Why longtext field slow up query? How to speed up my current database which must contain these 2 columns with longtext ? I didnt select these 2 columns to get.

Using laravel queries I got the same results.

Comment: missing [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)?

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you about this?

Comment: Yes @DmitriT INDEX was missing. So powerful to put INDEX on shop_id !!! You save my life. Thanbks a lot!

Comment: `ALTER catalogs CREATE INDEX shop_id (shop_id)` and try your query again.  To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. Show your execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LONGTEXT` columns are stored separately from the rest of the columns.  Extra disk fetches are used to load the value.

When you separated the `LONGTEXT` columns out, did you then fetch the value?  And that was slow, anyway?

Do you have `INDEX(shop_id)`?

Did Laravel do something dumb like preload the entire table?

What will you do with the PDF?  If you will only be writing them to a web page, it would be more efficient in multiple ways to store it as a file, then have HTML reference it.  This would probably be done via `<img src=...pdf>`.